# Ref and OUT behind the scenes

Tags: c#, .net

I'm wondering to know how ref and out keywords work behind the scenes?
For example in case we use it on method will it put this value type variable into some some class in order to work with it as with reference type?

Comment: In which level "behind the scenes"?

Comment: Have you checked msdn? It pretty much explains it. Simply put both are used to pass references instead of values to methods. That way you can for example have more than 1 return value in a method by simply using an `out`. Edit: You still have only one return value but can change a second value outside the method, namely the `out` variable

Comment: It is implemented as a *pointer*.  Tends to be rough on C# programmers, pointers are heavily abstracted away in the language.  Instead of the value, the caller passes the address of the value.  Where it is stored in memory, the way that the caller can see a change to its own local variable.  The callee always has to use a memory load or store to access the value, that can make code less efficient so one reason you have to declare it explicitly.  There is no distinction between ref and out at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

> in order to work with it as with reference type?

Firstly, you need to understand that "by reference" (`ref`/`out` and now `in`) **is not the same thing** as "reference type".

Ultimately, when you see:

```
void SomeMethod(ref int x);
```

here `x` is a reference, aka a "managed pointer" to a value; the caller supplies the reference. So, when you have:

```
int a = 123;
SomeMethod(ref a);
```

this works by taking the address of the variable `a` (usually via the `ldloca` or `ldflda` IL instruction), and passing that *address* in as the parameter value.

If the body of `SomeMethod` is:

```
void SomeMethod(ref int x) {
    Write(x);
    x = 12;
}
```

then the `Write(x)` *dereferences* the pointer `x` - it loads the value of `x`, looks at where it points, and gets an actual value *from there*. Likewise, the `x=12` takes the value `12`, looks at the pointer `x` and writes `12` to *where-ever that pointer points*.

To write the equivalent in `unsafe` C# with C# pointers (aka "unmanaged pointers") to show the difference:

```
void SomeMethod(int* x) {
    Write(*x);
    *x = 12;
}
int a = 123;
SomeMethod(&a);
```

---

`out` is just a fancy version of `ref` with certain "definite assignment" conventions; `in` is similarly a fancy version of `ref` that allows `readonly` types to work reliably and efficiently while avoiding stack copies.

Answer (score 1):

For the `ref` you can look at IL code generated for following code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x = 5;
    A(ref x);
}

private static void A(ref int x)
{
    x = 10;
}
```

you will see following:

```
.method public hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
    . . .
    IL_0001:  ldc.i4.5     //Push 5 onto the stack as int32.
    IL_0002:  stloc.0      //Pop a value from stack into local variable 0.
    IL_0003:  ldloca.s   x //Load address of local variable with index indx, short form.
    IL_0005:  call       void ConsoleApp1.Program::A(int32&) //Calls method A() by passing x's address to it
    . . . 
}
```

and the method A():

```
.method private hidebysig static void  A(int32& x) cil managed //x's address as argument
{
    // Code size       6 (0x6)
   .maxstack  8
   IL_0000:  nop
   IL_0001:  ldarg.0 //Load argument 0 onto the stack.
   IL_0002:  ldc.i4.s   10 //Push 10 onto the stack as int32, short form.
   IL_0004:  stind.i4 //Store value of type int32 into memory at address
   IL_0005:  ret
}
```

so basically it passes `x`s address to method `A()`, inside which the value of `10` will be written into memory with given address.

and finally for the `out`:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    A(out int x);
}

private static void A(out int x)
{
    x = 10;
}
```

the IL code would be:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  A([out] int32& x) cil managed
{
    . . .
    IL_0001:  ldloca.s   x //Load address of local variable with index indx, short form.
    IL_0003:  call       void ConsoleApp1.Program::A(int32&) //Calls method A() by passing x's address to it
    . . .
}
```

and the method A():

```
.method private hidebysig static void  A([out] int32& x) cil managed
{
  // Code size       6 (0x6)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldarg.0
  IL_0002:  ldc.i4.s   10
  IL_0004:  stind.i4
  IL_0005:  ret
} // end of method Program::A
```

as you can see only difference in `A(ref int x)` and `A(out int x)` methods is `[out]` method parameter attribute which will indicate that the parameter passed by `out` (not `ref`).